# How to change the dimension of the field in the type by DQL?

Tags: dql, alter, documentum, documentum6.5

How to change the dimension of the field in the type by DQL?

```
create type archik_type(
   archik_id ID,
   archik_number string(10)
)
supertype null
publish
go
```

How I can change from archik_number string(10) to string(256) ?
May be 'alter type' help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colleague helped me

```
alter type archik_type( 
modify archik_number string(256)
) 
publish
```

Comment: it's wrong.
the right answer is :
alter type archik_type
modify (archik_number string(256)
) 
publish